# How do I get the molarity of solution 1 given volume 1, molarity 2, and volume 2?

Tags: acid-base, solutions, titration

For example:

> What is the molarity of a $\ce{NaOH}$ solution if $25\rm~mL$ of the solution is exactly neutralized by $44\rm~mL$ of $0.32\rm~M~HCl$?

I know that the abstract function is

$$\text{Given Volume of Known Molarity} \times \text{Molarity Factor} \times \text{Mole Ratio} \times \text{Per Volume Factor} \times \text{Conversion Factor Per Liter}$$

Comment: @ A.J what are your workings out so far? The policy on this site is to not straight out answer homework questions without going through the OP's workings out first

Answer (score 1):

The reaction that occurs: H+ + OH- --> H2O

When you multiply the volume of HCl by the molarity of HCl you get the total amount of moles of H+ that reacted (mol/L x L = mol).
This means that the same amount of OH- was needed for the reaction (1:1). 
Volume of NaOH is known and thus yields the answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question or really make sense.

Comment: @Joel I disagree. It does in a way answer the question and it makes perfect sense. However, it would have been better suited as a comment since it is neither complete nor does the question itself comply with our homework policy.

Comment: @Martin , then why disagree? It's not the same amount , it's the same molar ratio. From there you can calculate the amount.